# How to Implement signature pad in blackberry 7?

Tags: blackberry, eclipse-plugin

I have started developing a Blackberry App in which it requires to implement sign pad. I googled about this and got a [link](https://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Adobe-AIR-Development/Signature-Capture-Sample-Code/ta-p/1184541) related to this. From this I am not able to view code through Abode Flash Player nor able to get other resource to implement sign pad.

Comment: I don't think this will ever be a viable thing on blackberry simply because not all devices have touch screens

Comment: @Kevin i want this to implement in Torch 9850 Device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find a reliable library for this. If you can't find any, your best bet would be to create your own by listening and drawing on a canvas.

Check out [this](https://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Capture-Signature-on-the-BlackBerry-Storm-smartphone/ta-p/442917) solution. It's likely not 100% complete, but its a start.

Comment: when executed a code as in the above link it shows me error like uncaught runtime Exception and pushModalScreen called by a non-event thread.

Comment: Have you tried `UiApplication.getUiApplication.invokeLater`?

Comment: ,no i have not used it.where should i put this.

Comment: Where ever you are trying to push `SignatureScreen` to the screen, that instruction should be on the UI Thread